# training prior network on conditional variational autoencoder

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, autoencoders

The objective function of the conditional VAE is defined as:

$L_{CVAE} = -KL(q(z|x,y)||p(z|x)) + \frac{1}{L}\sum_{l=1}^{L}\text{log } p(y|x,z^{(l)})$

Here x is input; y is output; z is latent variable. q(z|x,y) is recognition network. p(z|x) is prior network. p(y|x,z) is generation network.

How is the prior network, p(z|x), learned? In a regular VAE, the prior network would  just be p(z), which is fixed to be standard normal distribution. For reference, the objective function of the VAE is:

$L_{VAE} = -KL(q(z|x)||p(z)) + \frac{1}{L}\sum_{l=1}^{L}\text{log } p(x|z^{(l)})$

In the conditional VAE, the recognition and generation network can be backpropagated and trained. I don't see how p(z|x) can be trained. Is it okay to just use standard normal distribution for p(z|x) as well? It seems that this is what http://slazebni.cs.illinois.edu/spring17/lec12_vae.pdf (page 67) is suggesting.

Comment: There is no p(z|x) in page 67 its p(x|.), also for $L_{CVAE}$ it is p(z) same as VAE not p(z|x), see equation (1) in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.00570.pdf). If you are positive plz let me know to put it as answer

Comment: I checked equation 5 on this paper: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3f25/e17eb717e5894e0404ea634451332f85d287.pdf

Comment: You are right, that paper introduced its own prior that is modulated on x, i.e. $p_{\theta}(z|x)$. It has the same parameter as $p_{\theta}(z)$ so nothing would be different w.r.t. learning.

Comment: If it has the same parameter as $p_{\theta}(z)$ how is it dependent on x then?

Comment: No problem. When optimizing w.r.t. parameter $\theta$, neither $z$ nor $x$ matters in $p_{\theta}(z|x)$ because they are constant.

Comment: So during optimization, do you just try to make q(z|x,y) to be as similar to p(z|x) as possible and p(z|x) as similar to q(z|x,y) as possible? I feel like p isn't doing anything then because the only force affecting p's parameters is q. Suppose p and q are the same, the generation network's gradients will only change q. Since q is now different from p, then p would just make itself similar to q.

Comment: Not exactly. This question is valid for both VAE and CVAE. For CVAE, parameter $\theta$ is shared between $p_{\theta}(z|x)$ and $p_{\theta}(x|y,z)$. For VAE, take a look at Equation 3 in [Auto-Encoding Variational Bayes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6114), it is shared again.

Comment: Do you mean $p_{\theta}(y|x,z)$? How do they share weights though? The inputs and outputs have different dimensions.